# What is the best way of add sample data in rails application, fixtures or migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add a sample data to application using migration or fixtures , which is better? For example I have user model and want to add some sample user (foo,baar,baz)

Answer (score 4):

Neither, use the `db/seeds.rb` file. [Railscasts episode 179](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data) covers this nicely.